# Cómo realizar un where dinámico en SQL dependiendo del valor de la variable de entrada

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo un stored procedure con parámetros, y necesito hacer un select * from tabla where columna = valor siempre y cuando valor no sea null.
En otras palabras, cómo hacer para que en el caso de que la variable de entrada sea nula, el select no considere esa conidición?

```
create or replace procedure reporte7(fecha_inicio in date, fecha_fin in date, tipo_unidad in varchar2) as
    filas sys_refcursor;
begin
    open filas for select u.uni_placa, u.uni_tipo, 
                                h.uni_man_fecha_mantenimiento, h.uni_man_observaciones, h.uni_man_fecha_proxima
                                from unidad u join unidad_mantenimiento h 
                                on u.uni_id = h.uni_id 
                                where (h.uni_man_fecha_mantenimiento between fecha_inicio and fecha_fin)
                                and (u.uni_tipo = tipo_unidad);
    dbms_sql.return_result(filas);
end;
```

Por ejemplo, si el parámetro tipo_unidad es nulo, entonces que el select traiga todos las filas independientemente del valor de u.uni_tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente agrega el `OR` correspondiente en tu condición de `WHERE`:

```
WHERE (h.uni_man_fecha_mantenimiento between fecha_inicio and fecha_fin)
AND (u.uni_tipo = tipo_unidad)
AND (columna = valor OR valor IS NULL)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion NVL(expresion1, expresion2)

Quedando tu codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
create or replace procedure reporte7(fecha_inicio in date, fecha_fin in date, tipo_unidad in varchar2) as
    filas sys_refcursor;
begin
    open filas for select u.uni_placa, u.uni_tipo, 
                                h.uni_man_fecha_mantenimiento, h.uni_man_observaciones, h.uni_man_fecha_proxima
                                from unidad u join unidad_mantenimiento h 
                                on u.uni_id = h.uni_id 
                                where (h.uni_man_fecha_mantenimiento between fecha_inicio and fecha_fin)
                                and u.uni_tipo = **nvl(tipo_unidad, u.uni_tipo)**;
    dbms_sql.return_result(filas);
end;
```

Saludos
Israel Ramos